# Complex analysis - path integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I need to evaluate the following. $$\int_\gamma f(z) \: \text{d}z = \int_\gamma z^3+\cosh z \: \text{d}z$$ where $\gamma(t)=t^2+2it$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$. At first, I used the standard approach: $$\int_\gamma f(z) \: \text{d}z =\int_\gamma f(\gamma(t))\gamma '(t) \: \text{d}t=\left( (t^2+2it)^3 +\cosh(t^2+2it)\right)(2t+2i) \: \text{d}t.$$ But this seems ridiculous. Is there a better approach to this? Any tips would be great!

Comment: What tools/theorems do you have available?  Since $f(z)$ is analytic, the integral is independent of the path.   Moreover, we have useful antiderivatives for $z^3$ and $\cosh(z)$.

Comment: Ah, yes. So it is possible to change the path to a simpler one?

Comment: But it must still go between the same points as $\gamma$

Comment: Yes, but we only care about the end points and $\int f(z)\,dz=\frac14 z^4+\sinh(z)$.  I posted a solution.

Answer (score 2):

One can proceed as in the OP with

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz&=\int_\gamma (z^3+\cosh(z))\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^1 (t^2+2it)^3\,(2t+i2)\,dt+\int_0^1 \cosh(t^2+2it)\,(2t+i2)\,dt\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac14(t^2+2it)^4+\sinh(t^2+2it)\right)\right|_{0}^{1}\\\\
&=\frac14 (1+i2)^4+\sinh(1+i2)
\end{align}$$

But if one understands that since $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere, the value of the integral over any path from $(0,0)$ to $(1,2)$ is path independent, then one can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz&=\int_\gamma (z^3+\cosh(z))\,dz\\\\
&=\left.\left(\frac14 z^4+\sinh(z)\right)\right|_{z=0}^{z=1+i2}\\\\
&=\frac14 (1+i2)^4+\sinh(1+i2)
\end{align}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Analyticity does not always guarantee path independence, but in this case (entire function) it does.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I thought it is implicit since it the region of analyticity was not specified.  I edited and added the word "everywhere" after analytic.  ;-)) - Mark